# The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present. I'm out of ideias

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing a backend in MVC 5 for a client to update in their website. However I got across this error:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F0U9.png)
This is the controller with the methods with the AntiForgeryToken

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[System.web.Mvc.AuthorizeSectionccess(sectionname = "IT")] 
public ActionResult Create()
{
   return View();
}
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[System.web.Mvc.AuthorizeSectionccess(sectionname = "IT")]
[System.web.Mvc.AuthorizePermitionAccess(PermissonType = "Add")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Welcome_conteudoPage model)
{
   DB.Welcome_conteudoPage.Add(model);
   DB.SaveChanges();

   return Redirect("Index");
   return View(model);
}
```

And this is the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ConteudosPageController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ConteudoStandard)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Inserir" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        Texto:
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ConteudoStandard)
    </div>
}
```

I'm using the AntiForgeryToken on both ends and still get that error. I know that there are thousands of questions like this but I've tried all of the proposed solutions for 3 days and without any result.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the view is going to call the controller and model for a tinyMCE Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the answer, however, you may have misunderstood what the anti forgery token does and where to use it.

Firstly, when you use @Html.AntiforgeryToken in a view, it registers something in either the session or cookie (can't remember which).

The validate anti forgery token attribute looks for that token and matches it against the passed in token in the hidden field.  If it doesn't match, then most likely the post request didn't come from your view.

The thing to note, is that this requires a body parameter on the request to send in the token.  You wouldn't have this on requests that don't have a body.  A Get request doesn't have a body, and therefore doesn't need the validateantiforgerytoken attribute on it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I know what the anti forgery does, means and where to use it. The main problem is that the implementation is done (and in the right way I think) and if I did not messed up with the "core" code why is it not authorize the token?

Comment: Have you tried removing the validateantifirgerytoken attribute from the Create() method? That looks like a GET to me, it won't have an anti forgery token to validate

Comment: You were right, that was a get and I had the validate token in there. Even though I have the error. I'm now working without the anti forgery tokens till I finish the rest. If I find a solution I'll post it. And thank you again

Comment: As I said previously you were right, the get method does not need the verification token in it. I'm now using          System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(); as a temporary solution.